# How should I throw an exception if Some(null) is called?

Tags: scala, idioms

I've done `Some(Option(null).get)` but it looks a little strange.

---

Updated with sample. I can't compile check that the `text` is not null.

```
object Code {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(computeSomething("good"))
    println(computeSomething(null))
    def computeSomething(text: String): Option[String] =
      Some(Option(text).get).map("not null text was [" + _ + "]")
  }
}
//System.out:
//
//Some(not null text was [good])
//Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
//  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
//  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
//  at Code$.computeSomething$1(ZipInputLocation.scala:13)
//  at Code$.main(ZipInputLocation.scala:11)
//  at Code.main(ZipInputLocation.scala)
```

---

Updated with a second sample.

```
object Code {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(computeSomething("good"))
    println(computeSomething(null))
    def computeSomething(text: String): String = {
      require text != null
      //or
      //if(text == null)
      //  throw new RuntimeException("You broke the contract")
      "not null text was [" + text + "]"
    }
  }
}
//System.out:
//
//not null text was [good]
//Exception in thread "main" RuntimeException:
//  at Code$.computeSomething$1(ZipInputLocation.scala:13)
//  at Code$.main(ZipInputLocation.scala:11)
//  at Code.main(ZipInputLocation.scala)
```

Comment: Can you post an example ?

Comment: Using `.get` is unsafe/discouraged, using `Some(..)` with a not-pure value also.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Do you want to throw an exception if `null` is passed? Are you looking for how to deal with `null` idiomatically in _Scala_? In _Scala_ programs, you should never use `null`, nor should you throw exceptions (which violates _referential transparency_). If you have to interact with _Java_ programs that might pass `null` to your code, it's better to wrap such values in `Option` - as per my answer below - since that's a better way of dealing with an undefined value (which is typically the meaning of `null` in _Java_). But please clarify your intention...

Comment: BTW, your second example doesn't even mention `Some(null)`, so how does it relate to your original question?

Comment: It happened that my code needed an Option. In case this adds one unnecessary layer of confusion to the question I removed it.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `Option.get`. Instead, use the `Option.apply` and `map` on that, since it will return `None` for `null` values:

```
def computeSomething(text: String): Option[String] =
  Option(text).map("not null text was [" + _ + "]")
```

Even better, if you want to disallow someone to compile code explicitly passing `Some(null)` at compile time, use a tool like [WartMover](https://github.com/wartremover/wartremover), which has a specific rule for it that generates a compile time warning.

Comment: The OP wants to throw exception on `null`. I agree this is probably a bad design, but your answer does not address this and the code just behaves differently.

Comment: @Suma The fact that OP wants to throw doesn't mean I think it's the right choice, and doesn't force me to directly address it in my answer. If he doesn't like my choice of an answer he's free to choose not to accept it.

Comment: In my case receiving null as a parameter to computeSomething is a bug at the caller site. I was thinking that such cases are best handled by throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want `Some(null)` to throw an exception, instead of storing `null` as a value, correct?

Unfortunately, that's not going to happen. The only option you have is to put the creation of the `Some` instance inside a function and check for `null` explicitly. For example:

```
def wrapSome(s: String): Some[String] = {
  if(s eq null) throw new NullPointerException("Can't have null string!")
  Some(s)
}
```

Probably not what you wanted to hear, and not particularly useful either...

Alternatively, you could wrap the value in an `Option` (resulting in `None`, if the value is `null`), instead of in `Some` (which results in `Some(null)` if the value is `null`), and then call `.get`: `None.get` throws a `NoSuchElementException`. Indeed, this is exactly what you're doing in your example. (Is there a reason why you want to wrap the value explicitly with `Some` when that will happen automatically to non-`null` values wrapped in `Option`?)

One of the primary objectives of `Option` is to protect against `null` values.  Clearly, it would depend upon what you're trying to achieve, but *functional programing* discourages both `null` values and throwing of exceptions. If you're coming from *Java*, this can seem very strange, at first.

A more functional approach would be something like this:

```
// Return None if s is null; otherwise, Some(s). Both are Option[String] values.
def computeSomething(s: String): Option[String] = Option(s)

// Use this function to create an optional string.
val os = computeSomething(x) // x is some string. Could be null.

// Provide a default value if wrapped value is null (i.e. if os is None).
val a = os.getOrElse("some default value") // a is a string, never null.

// Do something with the value if it's not null; do nothing otherwise.
os.foreach(doSomething) // Calls doSomething(x), but only if x wasn't null/os isn't None.

// Process the string to something else. If os is None, result is None too.
val len = os.map(_.length) // Returns an Option[Int], None or Some(length of x)

// etc.
```

There's a whole host of idioms for using `Option` values like this, none of which involve throwing exceptions. If you could tell us more about what you're trying to do, I'll show you the *Scala*/*functional* way of doing it.

In the meantime, here's a reworked version of your program using this idiom with the `fold` method:

```
object Code
extends App { // No need for main function! ;-)

  println(computeSomething("good"))
  println(computeSomething(null))

  def computeSomething(text: String): String =
  Option(text).fold("text was null")(t => s"not null text was [$t]")
}

// System.out:
// not null text was [good]
// text was null
```